# Simple, intuitive example of non recursively enumerable languages

Tags: computability, turing-recognizable

This question is a bit of a shot in the dark. I am asking here, though I am not convinced that such an example exists.

I'd like a quick, highly intuitive example that I can throw out to my students *before* we engage in the halting problem. I will come back and explore RELs in more depth later in the lecture, but I was hoping for something I could use earlier in the lecture to help students *intuitively* see that there is a limit to what turing machines can represent before I get to a more formal exploration.

All of the examples I've found are very twisty, and would require me to stop and unpack the notion of the language before students could make any sense of them.  (i.e. they are not simply intuitive.)

I have no doubt that, within the infinity of NRE languages, there are some highly intuitive ones, but I've never seen one described *anywhere*, and I've looked for a long time.

Has anyone ever thought of such an example?

Comment: Do you wish for the language itself to be intuitive, or why it isn't recursively enumerable? If it is the first than the language of all multivariate polynomials with no integer roots might be good.

Comment: @CommandMaster The goal is to give an informal intuition prior to a more formal exploration, so it really must be both to work. And I wouldn't be surprised if no such language has been found :)

Comment: If they have enough background in logic to know Godel's first incompleteness theorem then the language of all true statements over the integers might be good. If not then I'm not sure, since the existence of NRE languages implies not all true statements have a proof, which isn't a very intuitive concepts

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps - if you want to avoid the Halting stuff - you can use the set $L$ of incompressible strings:

You start from the definition: a string $x$ is compressible if there is a TM (or a generic "program" in some programming language) smaller in size than $|x|$ that outputs $x$ (when run on empty input)

If there is a TM (a "program") $M$ that enumerates $L$ then you can build another TM $M'$ that simulates/mimics $M$ and as soon as it outputs a string $y$ larger than $|M'|$ it outputs $y$ and halts. The tricky part is to make them realize that a program can "know" its own size and can simulate another program.

In other words $M'$ generates an incompressible string $y$, but $|M'| < y$ so $y$ is compressible: a contradiction.